Is there a way to fix a boxplot that is showing up as lines rather than boxes. Never had an issue before?
ggplot(mean_mercury_by_tissue,aes(x=tissue,y=mean_concentration))+geom_boxplot
I have calculated mean mercury for each tissue which has generated a new table of data but the data is showing as one line per tissue rather than a box in the boxplot
